# Параллакс заголовка

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css-animation, parallax

Как можно сделать эффект параллакса для заголовка, чтобы при прокрутке страницы вниз заголовок не сразу прокручивался за пределы экрана, а притормаживал спускаясь немного ниже (к нижнему краю своей секции)?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

section:nth-child(1),
section:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: olivedrab;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background: seagreen;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  background: darkolivegreen;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>Подзаголовок 1</h2>
</section>
<section>
  <h3>Подзаголовок 2</h3>
</section>
<section>
  <h4>Подзаголовок 3</h4>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант на чистом CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: olivedrab;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

section>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin-x: 100%;
}

section>div>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.section__list {
  background: darkolivegreen;
}

section:nth-child(2) div {
  background: seagreen;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 3;
}

@supports (perspective: 1px) and (not (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch)) {
  main {
    height: 100vh;
    perspective: 1px;
    perspective-origin-x: 100%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  section:nth-child(1) {
    margin-bottom: 50vh;
  }
  .section__list {
    transform: translateZ(0);
  }
  .section__title {
    transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="section__title"><span>Заголовок</span></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="section__list"><span>Подзаголовок 1</span></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="section__list"><span>Подзаголовок 2</span></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="section__title"><span>Подзаголовок 3</span></div>
  </section>
</main>
```